# append one list Index to another list Index of different length

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

Getting this error : line 341, in upload
lst3 = lst1.extend(lst2)
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'extend'

---

```
{'Date': ['2_April','3_May','1_June','5_July', '3_April', '9_July'],
                    'State': ['BR', 'JH', 'HR', 'JH', 'BR', 'PB'],
                    'Blank': ['nan','nan','nan','nan','nan','nan'],
                    'District' : ['BS', 'GW', 'AM', 'RN', 'PB', 'GR'],
                    'nan': [Sub-dist, 0, 2, 2, 9, 8],
                    'nan': [Month, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'nan': [Year, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    'nan': [Facility,2, 3, 4, 0, 0],
                    }
```

---

```
    # Partial list of headers
    lst1 = df_.columns[:18]

    # converting first row to list and picking elements after 18th column
    lst2 = df_.iloc[1, 18:].to_numpy()

    lst2 = pd.Index(lst2)

    # extending lst to lst2
    lst3 = lst1.extend(lst2)
    print(lst3)

    # After merging two list Indexes above updating column of dataframe
    df_.columns = lst3
```

Comment: use `lst1 = df.columns[:18].tolist()` and `lst2 = pd.Index(lst2).tolist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    # Partial list of headers
    lst1 = df_.columns[:18].values

    # converting first row to list
    lst2 = df_.iloc[1, 18:].to_numpy()
    lst2 = pd.Index(lst2).values
    import numpy
    lst3 = numpy.concatenate((lst1, lst2))
    print(lst3)
    df_.columns = lst3
    df_ = df_[2:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `values` to convert indices/series into a list, like this

```
lst2 = pd.Index(lst2).values
```

Comment: Updated the answer now

Comment: Added, have a look